# Get specific data from jQuery JSON into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have tried almost everything, but can't figure this out?

I am creating a list view for my HTML app using JSON and this part was working just fine. But in the same JSON call I want to be able to send other data as well I can put into some variables but am unsuccessfull.

Here is what I am trying:

```
dataUrl = 'http://mypage.com/playermenu.php?callback=?&userid=' + userid,
dataCallback = function(data){
    //var content = data.list.join("");
    //var now = data.menutime; // HERE I WANT THE MENUTIME TO BE PUT INTO A VARIABLE //
    alert("Date: "+data.menutime);
    $('#userbar').html(data.profile); // FETCHING USERS DATA FOR PROFILEBAR //
    $('#games').html(content).listview('refresh');
}

$.getJSON(dataUrl, dataCallback);
```

The above alert gives: Date: undefined

My JSON looks like this:

```
([{"menutime":"2013-04-28 15:00:50"},{"profile":"troels"}])
```

Hoping for help with this.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why is the server adding the `()`? That makes it invalid JSON, which is rejected by `$.getJSON()`.

Take a look at the JavaScript console in your browser. It should have an error something like this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Is this your own server code? If so, you should fix it to produce valid JSON.

If you are stuck with using this invalid JSON format, then you should use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` instead of `$.getJSON()` and specify `"text"` format:

```js
$.get( dataUrl, dataCallback, 'text' );
```

Now your callback function will receive the bad JSON as plain text. So at the top of `dataCallback` you can remove the superfluous parentheses and parse the remaining JSON data:

```js
var data = $.parseJSON( data.match( /^\((.*)\)$/ )[1] );
```